# Error 503 for seemingly valid getIFPPlanQuotes request

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

I am using an XML I generated and as well as the one indicated on the sample but I am getting returned a `503 Service Unavailable`

Sample Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <p:PlanQuoteRequest xmlns:p="http://hios.cms.org/api" xmlns:p1="http://hios.cms.org/api-types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://hios.cms.org/api hios-api-11.0.xsd ">
  <p:Enrollees>
    <p1:DateOfBirth>1959-03-03</p1:DateOfBirth>
    <p1:Gender>Male</p1:Gender>
    <p1:TobaccoLastUsedMonths>2</p1:TobaccoLastUsedMonths>
    <p1:Relation>SELF</p1:Relation>
    <p1:InHouseholdIndicator>true</p1:InHouseholdIndicator>
  </p:Enrollees>
  <p:Enrollees>
    <p1:DateOfBirth>1982-03-03</p1:DateOfBirth>
    <p1:Gender>Female</p1:Gender>
    <p1:TobaccoLastUsedMonths>2</p1:TobaccoLastUsedMonths>
    <p1:Relation>SPOUSE</p1:Relation>
    <p1:InHouseholdIndicator>true</p1:InHouseholdIndicator>
  </p:Enrollees>
  <p:Location>
    <p1:ZipCode>22901</p1:ZipCode>
    <p1:County>
      <p1:FipsCode>51003</p1:FipsCode>
      <p1:CountyName>ALBEMARLE</p1:CountyName>
      <p1:StateCode>VA</p1:StateCode>
    </p1:County>
  </p:Location>
  <p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>2015-01-01</p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>
  <p:Market>Individual</p:Market>
  <p:IsFilterAnalysisRequiredIndicator>false</p:IsFilterAnalysisRequiredIndicator>
  <p:PaginationInformation>
    <p1:PageNumber>1</p1:PageNumber>
    <p1:PageSize>20</p1:PageSize>
  </p:PaginationInformation>
  <p:SortOrder>
    <p1:SortField>BASE RATE</p1:SortField>
    <p1:SortDirection>ASC</p1:SortDirection>
  </p:SortOrder>
</p:PlanQuoteRequest>
```

Comment: Not able to be reproduced, and not related to Open Data

Comment: Can you provide instruction to reproduce the error including link to the platform you are using or link to the API documentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relate to a system / server issue

Comment: but doesn't healthcare-finder-api point here for support? last line of content here does. https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services  i agree that this isn't "open data related", but where are these users supposed to go? another problem i have with organizations dumping their q&a/help forums here.....

Comment: user8840, could you please post the URL that results in this error? Thanks! I also think that this question is on-topic. healthcare-finder-api questions keep this site alive and give it some legitimacy, even if it means that we get an occasional server issue question.

Answer (score 1):

The system came back up. Must have been on CMS side.